# How to compile a specific file with tsc using the paths compiler option

Tags: typescript

I have several files I want to compile using a script. These files rely on the `paths` compile option to resolve its modules. As I want to target these files specifically I am bound to supplying them to `tsc` (as I don't want to create a separate `tsconfig.json` that targets these files for this task)

I've looked at the option to pass the `--path` parameter to `tsc`, but this is not allowed (`error TS6064: Option 'paths' can only be specified in 'tsconfig.json' file.`)

Can I somehow only compile specific `.ts` files while using the `paths` option?

**Update (22-06-17)**

As per request some specific examples:

The relevant settings in the `tsconfig.json` file are the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "Components/*": [
        "./src/Components/*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

so the relevant part is the paths setting, where you can create shorthands to import files from a certain directory. so you can import a file like `import {header} from 'Components/header.ts'` in stead of `import {header} from '../../Components/header.ts'`

But I need to compile specific files from the command line. But if I try:

```
tsc --project tsconfig.json entryFile.ts
```

it will give me the error:

```
error TS5042: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line.
```

and if I try to provide the `paths` option to the cli I get the following error:

```
error TS6064: Option 'paths' can only be specified in 'tsconfig.json' file.
```

Comment: Can you share an example? your question is not clear.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Specifying the input files on the command line voids your tsconfig.json.

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

From the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

So, there's no other option than to use a tsconfig.json with the proper 'include' (or exclude) specification of the files. The good news is that in the same docs you will find:

> A tsconfig.json file can inherit configurations from another file using the extends property.

So what you *can* do is overwrite the include property of your tsconfig with something like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
      "src/root/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

So you could make a script that:

1. Creates a temporary 'extends tsconfig' file with the desired 'include' property
2. Calls `tsc` with `--project` specified as that temporary tsconfig

One could argue that this is very complicated and question why they made the decision to not support this scenario properly. However, the question remains *why* one would like to compile just one file of a project. While developing, you can use the watch (`-w`) option to compile changes files, and upon building a full project you'll probably want to compile exactly that, the full project.

Comment: "However, the question remains why one would like to compile just one file of a project." -- The case I'm running into is real time linting of a file you're editing (in my case through vim-ale).

Comment: I wanted to [generate declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746095/581205) for a single file, but for it to compile, I had to specify options, which are already included in the tsconfig. It was just `--target ES5 --jsx react`, so no big deal, but there are many more options there, which may be relevant, too (or not; I'm new to TS and I didn't wrote the config).

Comment: RE: "why one would like to compile just one file of a project" - I am currently trying to create a simple repro to debug a problem

Comment: why...because I am writing a script and just want to test the one

Comment: Why?  Because I want to pass the `--traceResolution` flag and only get the output for one file, as otherwise, it's too difficult to find what I'm looking for in the flood of output for a large project.

Comment: Same here -- just trying to debug things, so I want to see what tsc generates for this one file.

Comment: Another case here: traceResolution output is ridiculously long. I was able to speed up my use-case (splitting huge change into smaller PRs) with this: ```tsc -p some/path/tsconfig.temp.json --traceResolution | ggrep "was successfully resolved to" | ggrep -v "node_modules"```

Comment: Why? Because i want to further obfuscate the output of tsc.

Comment: This transpiled all the files included by the only one listed in "include."  I just want one single file transpiled, am I in the wrong place?

Comment: "Why?" Because I want to compile just integration tests and run them in a CI flow

Answer (score 15):

I was in a similar need for making sure the project will compile using [lint-staged](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#readme).  If the combination of `tsconfig.json` and file paths were allowed, you could use `"tsc"` directly as a lint-staged command.

As a workaround I created the following helper script `scripts/tsc-lint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -e

TMP=.tsconfig-lint.json
cat >$TMP <<EOF
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
EOF
for file in "$@"; do
  echo "    \"$file\"," >> $TMP
done
cat >>$TMP <<EOF
    "unused"
  ]
}
EOF
tsc --project $TMP --skipLibCheck --noEmit
```

Then the lint-staged config contains:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "{src,tests}/**/*.ts": [
      "scripts/tsc-lint.sh"
    ]
  },
```

The file `.tsconfig-lint.json` is added to `.gitignore`.

Comment: I'd recommend replacing `"unused"` with `"**/*.d.ts"`.

Comment: This was still producing type errors outside my staged files so I replaced the last line with this: `FILES_WITH_ERRORS=$(tsc --project $TMP --noEmit --skipLibCheck | cut -d '(' -f 1); for file in "$@"; do grep -v "$file"<<<"$FILES_WITH_ERRORS" >/dev/null; done`

Comment: When I add multiple files in this temporary `tsconfig.json`, `tsc` will stop checking more files if any of them fails. Does it actually checks all the files in your include array even if there are type errors in more than just one?

Answer (score 13):

*Just to build upon @Bram's answer...*

What I do in my project is have two tsconfigs:

```
project/
   dist/
   docs/
   src/
   package.json
   tsconfig.json
   tsconfig-build.json
```

So I have a `tsconfig-build.json` (because I don't want `docs/` included in my build):

```
// tsconfig-build.json

{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Then you could have a line in `package.json`:

```
// package.json
  ...
  
  "scripts": {

    ...
    
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig-build.json"
  },
```

Comment: build command should be 1 of the following:
`tsc -p tsconfig-build.json` OR
`tsc --project tsconfig-build.json`

Comment: This is exactly what I'd like to do, but unfortunately, `-p` seems in incompatible with TS projects in NPM workspaces which use references and the `composite` property

Answer (score 5):

`--noResolve` is the key here:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noResolve

As an example:

```
// tsconfig.myFile.json
{
  // "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "myFile.ts"
  ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noResolve": true
    }
}
```

`$ tsc --project tsconfig.myFile.json`

There are also ways of including `--noResolve` and some output flag to do this with just command line.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @sampo's answer.

We can create a temporary `.tsconfig-lint.json` in each package directory, that includes a list of staged TS files belonging under each respective directory.

It will run a `tsc` for each package and report any status codes that are not 0.

```js
// <root>/tsc-lint.js

// Usage: `yarn lint-staged` (doesn't support --relative)
// In package.json."lint-staged"."*.{ts,tsx}": `node ./tsc-lint.js`
// Run from workspace root

const chalk = require('chalk');
const spawn = require('cross-spawn');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Relative path of package locations (relative to root)
const packages = [
  'packages/a',
  'packages/b',
  'packages/c',
];

const TSCONFIG_LINT_FILE_NAME = '.tsconfig-lint.json';

const files = process.argv.slice(2);

Promise.all(
  packages.map((package) => {
    const absolutePackagePath = path.resolve(package);

    const includedFiles = files.filter((file) => file.startsWith(absolutePackagePath));

    if (includedFiles.length) {
      const tsconfig = {
        extends: './tsconfig.json',
        include: [...includedFiles, '**/*.d.ts'],
      };

      const tsconfigLintPath = `${package}/${TSCONFIG_LINT_FILE_NAME}`;

      fs.writeFileSync(tsconfigLintPath, JSON.stringify(tsconfig, null, 2));

      return spawn.sync(path.resolve('./node_modules/.bin/tsc'), [
        '--project',
        tsconfigLintPath,
        '--noEmit',
        '--skipLibCheck',
      ]);
    }

    return undefined;
  }),
)
  .then((children) => Promise.all(children.filter((child) => child && child.status !== 0)))
  .then((children) => Promise.all(children.map((child) => child.stdout)))
  .then((errors) => {
    if (errors.length) {
      throw errors;
    }

    return errors;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(chalk.red(error));

    process.exit(2);
  });
```

```
// <root>/.gitignore
.tsconfig-lint.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved exactly this using the compiler API.  This is a (greatly) modifed
version of [their minimal compiler example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#a-minimal-compiler).

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as cp from 'child_process';
import * as dm from '../src-ts/deep-merge-objects';
function compile(fileNames: string[], options: ts.CompilerOptions): void {
  const program = ts.createProgram(fileNames, options);
  const emitResult = program.emit();

  const allDiagnostics = ts
    .getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)
    .concat(emitResult.diagnostics);

  allDiagnostics.forEach((diagnostic) => {
    if (diagnostic.file) {
      const {line, character} = diagnostic.file.getLineAndCharacterOfPosition(
        diagnostic.start!
      );
      const message = ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(
        diagnostic.messageText,
        '\n'
      );
      console.log(
        `${diagnostic.file.fileName} (${line + 1},${character + 1}): ${message}`
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        ts.flattenDiagnosticMessageText(diagnostic.messageText, '\n')
      );
    }
  });

  const exitCode = emitResult.emitSkipped ? 1 : 0;
  console.log(`Process exiting with code '${exitCode}'.`);
  process.exit(exitCode);
}

function main(): void {
  fs.mkdirSync('./dev-out',{recursive:true})
  cp.execSync('cp -r ./testlib-js ./dev-out/');

  const tscfgFilenames = [
    '@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json',
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'tsconfig.base.json'),
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'tsconfig.json'),
  ];
  const tscfg = tscfgFilenames.map((fn) => require(fn).compilerOptions);
  const compilerOptions: ts.CompilerOptions = dm.deepMerge(
    dm.deepMergeInnerDedupeArrays,
    ...tscfg
  );

  if (compilerOptions.lib && compilerOptions.lib.length)
    compilerOptions.lib = compilerOptions.lib.map((s) => 'lib.' + s + '.d.ts');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(compilerOptions, null, 2));
  compile(process.argv.slice(2), compilerOptions);
}
try {
  main();
  if (process.exitCode === 1) console.log('compiler produced no output');
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
  process.exitCode = 2;
}
```

The gotcha's were

- Reading in the config file(s).  That was not included in the original example.
- Merging the config files in order. (Not a problem if you use a single file).
- Transforming the `compilerOptions.lib` entries

```
if (compilerOptions.lib && compilerOptions.lib.length)
    compilerOptions.lib = compilerOptions.lib.map((s) => 'lib.' + s + '.d.ts');
```

E.g., "es2020" is changed to "lib.es2020.d.ts".

The generic object merging code is here:

```
// adapted from  adrian-marcelo-gallardo
// https://gist.github.com/ahtcx/0cd94e62691f539160b32ecda18af3d6#gistcomment-3257606
//
type objectType = Record<string, any>;

export const isObject = (obj: unknown): obj is objectType => {
  return <boolean>obj && typeof obj === 'object';
};
export function deepMerge(
  deepMergeInner: (target: objectType, source: objectType) => objectType,
  ...objects: objectType[]
): objectType {
  if (objects.length === 0) return {};
  if (objects.length === 1) return objects[0];
  if (objects.some((object) => !isObject(object))) {
    throw new Error('deepMerge: all values should be of type "object"');
  }
  const target = objects.shift() as objectType;
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(target,null,2))
  let source: objectType;
  while ((source = objects.shift() as objectType)) {
    deepMergeInner(target, source);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(target,null,2))
  }
  return target;
}

export function deepMergeInnerDedupeArrays(
  target: objectType,
  source: objectType
): objectType {
  function uniquify(a: any[]): any[] {
    return a.filter((v, i) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
  }
  Object.keys(source).forEach((key: string) => {
    const targetValue = target[key];
    const sourceValue = source[key];
    if (Array.isArray(targetValue) && Array.isArray(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = uniquify(targetValue.concat(sourceValue));
    } else if (isObject(targetValue) && Array.isArray(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = sourceValue;
    } else if (Array.isArray(targetValue) && isObject(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = sourceValue;
    } else if (isObject(targetValue) && isObject(sourceValue)) {
      target[key] = deepMergeInnerDedupeArrays(
        Object.assign({}, targetValue),
        sourceValue
      );
    } else {
      target[key] = sourceValue;
    }
  });
  return target;
}
```

Another this is directory structure.  You might not get the same output directory as your get with all files unless you use
`compilerOptions.rootDir`.  Typically:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dev-out",
    "rootDir": "./"
  },
```

Read about [rootDir here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#rootDir)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-liner shell script function you can use for testing purpose. It's based on [@Sampo's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60950355/1405998).

```bash
tsc -p $(ts_extend "src/temp.ts") --outDir dist-other
```

```bash
function ts_extend() {
  local include_file=$1
  TS_IIFE_CONFIG=.tsconfig-extend.json
  echo '{ "extends": "./tsconfig.json", "include": ["'${include_file}'"] }' > $TS_IIFE_CONFIG
  echo $TS_IIFE_CONFIG
}
```

You can quickly add more fancy stuff and do more, but this is the minimal thing I've needed.

The official reply from the typescript team seems to be "make it as a system, so IDEs and build tools can use it", but from time to time I come up with the needs to test some things out. Debugging part of the code, testing out configurations and stuff.

I won't save this under my `.profile` file, but place it somewhere I can reference it later, and copy & edit & paste as I need it. ([gist](https://gist.github.com/jangxyz/095227fdb180b12822544200a59c0091))