# How to generate “*.d.ts” in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

How to generate “*.d.ts” in typescript or creates and import @types?
Is there any way to create d.ts for jquery plugin or plain javascript library?

Comment: if it's your own code witten in typescript you can enable the generation as a compiler option. if it's a thirdparty not written in typescript you have to write them manually.

Comment: If no one else have created a definition for `@types/your-jquery-thingie` you can do so yourself, see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/#how-can-i-contribute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you produce a .d.ts "typings" definition file from an existing JavaScript library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687779/how-do-you-produce-a-d-ts-typings-definition-file-from-an-existing-javascript)

Answer (score 10):

File `.d.ts` is a declaration file.For details [see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).


To create `.d.ts` from a `ts` file.You only need to add the `-d` or `--declaration` parameter during compile using `tsc`.


**Example:**

```
tsc -d your_ts_file.ts
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to create the declaration file only, without producing other `.js` files, you can run the compiler with the `emitDeclarationOnly` option

```
tsc --emitDeclarationOnly
```

Here is a full list of available [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

Answer (score 1):

For your own code, this can be done with a compiler option:

```
tsc --sourceMap=true
```

This can also be added to your tsconfig file, as well as MSBuild task.

For jQuery, most of those libraries are on DefinitelyTyped, where you can install them via `@types/LIBRARY_NAME`.

For other third party libraries, you may have to create them yourself; otherwise, you can allow JavaScript with another compiler option:

```
tsc --allowJs=true
```

Then depending on your loading tool, you can use `require` or some other mechanism to import.