# calling a JS function of an NPM module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have a react native project running on typescript, is working fine, now I've added a library 
[react-native-fingerprint-scanner](https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner)
from NPM, but I'm having problems calling a function?

So the project works fine on JS:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    FingerprintScanner
      .isSensorAvailable()
      .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
  }
```

But if I call the same way

> componentDidMount

On typeScript project, I get:

> TypeError: FingerprintScanner.isSensorAvailable is not a function.(In 'FingerprintScanner.isSensorAvailable' is undefined)

Note, I have to import with

```
const FingerprintScanner = require('react-native-fingerprint-scanner');
```

because If I import with

```
import { FingerprintScanner } from 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner';
```

I get this error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner'

So, how to get TS to recognize this function? cheers

Comment: Generate own https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101769/how-to-generate-d-ts-in-typescript. Or mabe find already exising https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you want to use a library from npm, which does not provide its own type definitions, you need to either get it from DefinitelyTyped or write them yourself. Looking at the module name, I checked that there are no typescript definitions for `react-native-fingerprint-scanner`. If you want to use this module in your project, create a new `custom.d.ts` file along with your other typescript files as follows.

```
declare module "react-native-fingerprint-scanner" {
  const data: any
  export default data
}
```

Now, you'll need to import it into the file that you want:

```
import FingerPrintScanner from "react-native-fingerprint-scanner"
```

You'll be able to use the npm module now. If you want stricter typings, you can write your own typings in the module inside custom.d.ts. [This](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html) will guide you to write library declaration typings.

If you do write the typings for this npm module, consider uploading them onto DefinitelyTyped.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to TS Modules:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

According to docs, you have to do that:
`import FingerprintScanner from 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner';`

Also refer to fingerPrint doc, where you will find same example:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { AlertIOS } from 'react-native';
import FingerprintScanner from 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner';

class FingerprintPopup extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    FingerprintScanner
      .authenticate({ description: 'Scan your fingerprint on the device scanner to continue' })
      .then(() => {
        this.props.handlePopupDismissed();
        AlertIOS.alert('Authenticated successfully');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.props.handlePopupDismissed();
        AlertIOS.alert(error.message);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return false;
  }
}

FingerprintPopup.propTypes = {
  handlePopupDismissed: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default FingerprintPopup;
```

Comment: hi, I have to import as const, because with normal import I get: "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-fingerprint-scanner'"

Comment: `npm install react-native-fingerprint-scanner`