# How can I get a Typescript script to use the paths defined in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, import, scripting, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

In my NodeJS/Typescript project, I created a script `database-init.script.ts` that I run to initialize the database with sample data.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
   "name": "myproject",
   ....
   "scripts": {
      ...
      "mongodb-setup": "tsc ./scripts/mongodb-setup.ts && node ./scripts/mongo-setup.js"
      
}
```

The problem is that the script imports some files that themselves utilize tsconfig `paths` shortcuts. For example some files have

```
import {AccountSchema} from '@schemas/account.schema'
...
```

My script fails because it doesn't recognize these. It gives me

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@schemas/account.schema' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import {AccountSchema} from '@schemas/account.schema";
```

**How can I get a script to recognize tsconfig-defined paths, without compiling the entire project?**

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup? How are you running this script? Are you first compiling to .js & running it, or are you using something like ts-node / deno? Are you using these custom paths in imports anywhere else in the project? If so do you see errors there? Are you able to share a minimum reproducible example on github?

Comment: @GeorgeJose I added the relevant part of my package.json. I can put together a minimal project to demonstrate the issue if nobody has any ideas after some time.

Comment: You might find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44676944/how-to-compile-a-specific-file-with-tsc-using-the-paths-compiler-option/44748041 - TLDR; [you cannot use the paths option in the CLI](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) - it's tsconfig.json only. Providing input files causes tsc to not read the `tsconfig`. You can get around it by creating a separate tsconfig just for your script that extends your base tsconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  ....
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "ts-node": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "mongodb-setup": "node -r ts-node/register ./scripts/mongo-setup.ts"
  }
}
```