# How to check typescript type before commit?

Tags: git, typescript

I want to check typescript type before commit, So i use `tsc --noEmit $(changedFile)`. However, This command can not specify `config` file.

I found `--project` option, But this option will check entire project and i just want to check `changedFile`, Because some `old files` has type error but do not need to handle.

So how can i only check `changedFile` type before commit ?

Answer (score 13):

You can use an awesome tool called `lint-staged`.
This library **lint your files before each** commit.   https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged

**Installation**

```
npx mrm lint-staged
```

**Usage** *for TypeScript*

```js
// lint-staged.config.js
module.exports = {
  '**/*.ts?(x)': () => 'tsc -p tsconfig.json --noEmit'
}
```

Comment: i just want to check changed files on current commit.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and this package helped me for checking types in the lint-staged:

```
"**/*.ts?(x)": [
  "tsc-files --noEmit"
]
```

you can install `tsc-files` package with `npm i tsc-files`

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use a `pre-commit` hook (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

It it, you can get the files about to be commited with `git diff --staged --name-only` you could then run your `tsc --noEmit $(changedFile)`.

Comment: `tsc --noEmit $(changedFile)` can not specify typescript config file.

Answer (score -1):

`tsc` doesn't provide a direct way to process specified files with the project settings (if you pass files to `tsc`, it [ignores the config file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27379)), but it does allow you to [extend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748041) a config file and override its list of included files, e.g.:

```sh
$ cat ./tsconfig-temp.json
```

```json
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["./temp.ts"]
}
```

A wrapper script can be used to generate a config file like this on the fly with the specified file(s), e.g. (using [`jo`](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) to create the JSON):

```sh
$ cat tsc-files.sh
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

TEMP='./tsconfig-temp.json'
trap 'rm "$TEMP"' EXIT

jo extends=./tsconfig.json include=$(jo -a "$@") > $TEMP \
    && tsc --noEmit --project "$TEMP"
```

### usage

```sh
$ tsc-files.sh ./temp.ts
```

Alternatively, you can use the [tsc-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-files) package on npm, which does this for you:

### usage

```sh
$ tsc-files --noEmit ./temp.ts
```