# TypeScript Error: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[][]'

Tags: typescript

## Property `flat` does not exist on type `string[][]`

### Several similar questions exist on SO. Their answers are to add `es2019` to the --lib tag in the `tsconfig.json`, but doing this doesn't help my issue.

```
$ node --version
v14.17.1
$ tsc --version
Version 4.3.5
$ tsc src/index.ts
src/index.ts:6:41 - error TS2550: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[][]'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2019' or later.

6 let flat_array: string[] = nested_array.flat();
```

src/index.ts

```
let nested_array: string[][] = [
  ["1", "2"],
  ["3", "4"],
];

let flat_array: string[] = nested_array.flat();

console.log(flat_array);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "lib": [
        "es2019",
        "DOM"
      ],
      "module": "commonjs",
      "declaration": true,
      "outDir": "./lib",
      "strict": true
    },
    "include": ["src/"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
  }
```

I've tried older version of node (v10), and different versions of typescript (3.7.3) too. I've run typescript from dev dependencies as npm script, and using globally installed typescript as well. This error does not go away. I also tried closing and re-opening VSCode.

In case you are interested, here is the `package.json` file too. I tried running with `npm start` in addition to globally installed typescript, but this throws the same error.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "16.3.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: `"target": "es5"` - I think you need to change this, not just lib

Answer (score 2):

Change target to `Es2019`. Here is working sample:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Working Code:

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/DYUwLgBAdiDOYgCYH0CGAndqCeAuC86AllAOYDaAulRALwTkCwAUBAwEQCM7ANBOwCZ2lHizbl2AZl78ALMNHNKAbhYtQkAGbBUYNJhz5CJCpTrQ4CFBizYAdNt0AKAJSrmLAMYB7KLG%20gdsDepE6OejY4bkA)

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I see that it works in the playground. It is still not working on my computer. There is no 'lib' tag in your examples. I am trying with and without, etc. Even adopting your new configs does not help. How can I break the tsconfig.json file to make sure that new versions are actually being read? It is almost like the program isn't reading the newly saved tsconfig file...

Comment: If I save an empty tsconfig.json file `{}` then I still get the same error. Shouldn't I get a different error regarding the lack of information in the tsconfig.json file??

Comment: I run this code in my visual studio with this config and everything it's ok.
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2019"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]`

Comment: Which version of typescript you are using?

Comment: $ tsc --version
Version 4.3.5

Comment: Have you tried my config in your `tsconfig.json`? Please save and restart your idea after copy and paste the config

Comment: running `$ tsc index.ts` returns the error. But, running `$ tsc index.ts --target es2019` in the terminal with no tsconfig.json file does NOT throw an error, but nor does it log the resulting array like it should.

Comment: Yes, I've tried your config. I'm starting to think the config files aren't being read at all by typescript. Very frustrating. I think I'm going to update vscode, and restart.

Comment: Yes I think apart from config you have some other problem with your `IDE`

Comment: I just got partly working by installing ts-node (https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#usage). I can delete the tsconfig.json. `npm i -D ts-node typescript tslib @types/node` and now I can run the code no errors and the console.log() shows in command line using this command `npx ts-node src/index.ts`. Not sure if this is an answer yet, need to understand a bit more what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Running `tsc src/idnex.ts` won't pick up your `tsconfig.json`, as stated by the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

```sh
# Emit JS for just the index.ts with the compiler defaults
tsc index.ts
```

(**with the compiler defaults**)

`tsc` doesn't support arguments like `-p tsconfig.json src/index.ts` either. There is no way to compile a single file with `tsconfig.json`.

---

Two workarounds:

1. Specify your compiler options in command line.
2. Create a new `tsconfig.singlefile.json`, put your source file in the `include` option. See this exact same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44748041/1179747).

Answer (score 0):

Updating dependencies `ts-node typescript @types/node` helped me in the same situation.

No `tsconfig` lib update needed if the `target` in your `tsconfig` is already 2019+